# Does the piece of music being played by Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes have an in-universe name?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, music-identification

In the famous cantina scene from "A New Hope", there is a band playing an upbeat song. In subsequent works we find out the name of the band (Figrin D'an and the Modal Nodes), the genre of music they were playing (Jizz), and their species (Bith). Do we ever find out what the name of the song was?

On the official soundtracks it is usually called "Cantina Band", however presumably that's not an in-universe name.

Comment: Apparently, a heck of a lot of Australians [_have sex_](http://mashable.com/2017/02/14/cantina-band-song-sex/#o41wJFQNZOqU) with this song in the background, which I think is consistent with it's in-universe name. To quote Himarm, [nothing in australia makes sense](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=35651900#35651900)

Comment: highly relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=84WpcmJ28Yg

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Mad About Me](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_About_Me)

The song is [first named](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Mad_About_Me/Legends#Behind_the_scenes) in the Legends/EU story ["Empire Blues: The Devaronian's Tale"](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Empire_Blues:_The_Devaronian%27s_Tale) in 1995's *Tales from the Mos Eisley Cantina*:

> The story tells how Kardue'sai'Malloc was forced into hiding and how he "arranges" for the Modal Nodes to play at Chalmun's Spaceport Cantina in Mos Eisley.

The name is also used in 2015's *Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know*; despite its release date and the fact that it's used internally by Lucas Licensing, [the non-Legends canonicity of its contents is disputed](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know#Canonicity).

Comment: Which one, though? In the movie (and on the soundtrack) there are two songs, listed as "Cantina Band 1" (the more famous, doot DEET doot DEET doDEET doo, q=~260) and "Cantina Band 2" (lots of flourishes, q=~190). Might the other one be "Worm Case"?